# add_action not working in header?

Tags: theme-development, actions, init

i need to enable the session variables to my theme , so i have the following code in my theme functions.php

```
function session_manager() {
  if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();

  // Get variables in query string
$loc= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = preg_replace('/\\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$loc = explode("/", $loc);
$loc=$loc[1];
global $storelocation;
global $right_side_bar;
global $header_right;

  $_SESSION['location'] = ucfirst(strtolower($loc));
  $storelocation= $_SESSION['location'];
  $right_side_bar=$storelocation."-Right-sidebar"; 
   $header_right=$storelocation."-Right-header"; 

  }
}
add_action('init', 'session_manager', 1);
```

`$right_side_bar` is working fine while echo this in right sidebar it showing the session value, but `echo $header_right` is not working in header, i already tried with  `wp_head instead of init in add_action` it cause `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent`

Comment: if the function is being added to `init` consider putting it in the `functions.php` page.
Also , try to use it after the call of `wp_head()`.

Comment: yes it is in functions.php

Comment: Your code works for me when I test it. If it is not working for you I have to guess that there is information missing from the description of the problem.